# Dúvida sobre o Git - branch master

Tags: git

Reparem na imagem abaixo, não estou mais dentro do diretório onde se encontra o meu repositório do Git, porém o branch master continua aparecendo. Por que?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se tem a ver com o git em si, pode ser um bug do shell

Comment: Hmm, tentei reinstalar o Git bash, mas não funcionou. Sabes como posso tentar consertar? @DenisRudneideSouza

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de qual sistema operacional está usando (Windows, Linux, etc), e qual shell está usando (bash, zsh, etc). Nos informe também como a variável `PS1` está definida, já que é nela que fica definida string do prompt. Dê uma checada também se, por engano, não foi criado um diretório `.git` no home do seu usuário...

Comment: @EduardoBaitello, você acertou, era um diretório .git criado por engano. Obrigado.

Comment: Se alguém puder sinalizar como respondida, agradeço. Sou novo aqui e ainda não conheço as boas práticas etc, vou me informar. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá João. Adicionei como comentário pois pedi informações adicionais do problema. Porém, idealmente soluções devem ser postadas como resposta (escrevi uma resposta agora com o que te faria achar a solução da mesma forma). Dê uma olhada aqui para entender melhor [Como e porque aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) e sobre os "votos a favor".

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoBaitello, Eduardo, onde posso encontrar as boas práticas do Stack? Quero me adequar a comunidade.

Comment: Recomendo que comece pelo [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender os conceitos principais (você inclusive irá ganha uma medalha por completá-lo). Na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) você pode encontrar questões frequentes, incluindo as de boas práticas referente as perguntas, respostas, comportamento e etc. Se ainda sim tiver alguma dúvida sobre como usar o site, você pode usar o https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ para procurar por sua resposta ou até mesmo fazer uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A configuração responsável pelo string do prompt é feita pela [variável `PS1`](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Customizando-o-BASH). Supondo Linux + bash, essa variável deve estar definida no `.bashrc` do seu usuário.

Se estiver tudo certo com a configuração da `PS1` o problema geralmente é um diretório `.git` criado no lugar indevido. Verifique o home do seu usuário se você possui um `.git` que não deveria estar ali. Apague/mova-o se necessário.

Comment: Obrigado @EduardoBaitello. Era um arquivo `.git` criado indevidamente no meu diretório home.